# Image name returned as undefined, but only for some

Tags: javascript, image, select, menu, rotation

In short: I'm using the same JS function to rotate an image that could come from several categories, and it works for perfectly for all categories except 1. I'm totally stumped.

Details: I'm writing a javascript app to make cocktail recipes. The ingredients to the recipes are brought in to javascript via php/mysql. I've tested these variables in JavaScript & PHP and they are all being populated properly.

```
//Function to store db table in to two dimensional $array[id][attribute]

function getRows($table, $mysql) {

$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table;
$result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // You have $row['id'], $row['name'], $row['image']

            $var[$row['id']] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'image' => $row['image']);
            $var['num'] = $num;


    }

}
return $var;
}

//Use the function above to populate all the PHP variables, then convert each to Javascript


echo "<script>\n";
$actions = getRows('actions', $mysql);
$js_actions = json_encode($actions);
echo "var actions = ". $js_actions . ";\n";

$bottles = getRows('bottles', $mysql);
$js_bottles = json_encode($bottles);
echo "var bottles = ". $js_bottles . ";\n";

$garnishes = getRows('garnishes', $mysql);
$js_garnishes = json_encode($garnishes);
echo "var garnishes = ". $js_garnishes . ";\n";

$mixers = getRows('mixers', $mysql);
$js_mixers = json_encode($mixers);
echo "var mixers = ". $js_mixers . ";\n";
```

Outputs this to the browser

```
<script>
var actions = {"1":{"id":"1","name":"Stir","image":"stir.png"},"num":3,"2":{"id":"2","name":"Shake","image":"ShakeAndStrain.png"},"3":{"id":"3","name":"Muddle","image":"muddle.png"}};
var bottles = {"1":{"id":"1","name":"Bourbon","image":"jim_beam.png"},"num":2,"2":{"id":"2","name":"Sugar","image":"GARNISH_SugarCube.png"}};
var garnishes = {"1":{"id":"1","name":"Orange and Cherry","image":"GARNISH_orange-AND-cherry.png"},"num":2,"2":{"id":"2","name":"Sugar Cube","image":"GARNISH_SugarCube.png"}};
var mixers = {"1":{"id":"1","name":"Water","image":"Not yet"},"num":4,"2":{"id":"2","name":"Soda","image":"SODA_7UP_soda_dispenser_soda_gun.png"},"3":{"id":"3","name":"Bitters","image":"BITTERS_blood_orange_bitters.png"},"4":{"id":"4","name":"Sugar","image":"GARNISH_SugarCube.png"}};
</script>
```

For each ingredient of the drink, there are two drop down menus that sit above an image. The first drop down you can pick action, bottle, mixer, or garnish. When you pick one of those categories, it populates the second drop down with the ingredients stored in the respective mysql table.

```
function configureDropDownLists(select1,select2,actions,bottles,mixers,garnishes) {

    switch (select1.value) {
        case 'action':
            document.getElementById(select2).options.length = 1;
            for (i = 1; i <= actions['num']; i++) {
                createOption(document.getElementById(select2), actions[i]['name'], actions[i]['id'], actions[i]['image']);
            }
            break;
        case 'bottle':
            document.getElementById(select2).options.length = 1; 
        for (i = 1; i <= bottles['num']; i++) {
            createOption(document.getElementById(select2), bottles[i]['name'], bottles[i]['id']), bottles[i]['image'];
            }
            break;
        case 'mixer':
            document.getElementById(select2).options.length = 1;
            for (i = 1; i <= mixers['num']; i++) {
                createOption(document.getElementById(select2), mixers[i]['name'], mixers[i]['id'], mixers[i]['image']);
            }
            break;
         case 'garnish':
            document.getElementById(select2).options.length = 1;
            for (i = 1; i <= garnishes['num']; i++) {
                createOption(document.getElementById(select2), garnishes[i]['name'], garnishes[i]['id'], garnishes[i]['image']);
            }
            break;
            default:
                document.getElementById(select2).options.length = 0;
            break;
    }

}

function createOption(select1, text, value, image) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = value;
    opt.text = text;
    opt.myImage = image;
    select1.options.add(opt);
}
```

then below...

```
                      <td>
                    <select id="step1" name='step1' onChange="configureDropDownLists(this,'step1_id',actions,bottles,mixers,garnishes)">
                        <option value="0">Choose category</option>
                        <option value="action">Action</option>
                        <option value="bottle">Bottle</option>
                        <option value="mixer">Mixer</option>
                        <option value="garnish">Garnish</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select id='step2' name='step2'  onChange="configureDropDownLists(this,'step2_id',actions,bottles,mixers,garnishes)">
                        <option value="0">Choose category</option>
                        <option value="action">Action</option>
                        <option value="bottle">Bottle</option>
                        <option value="mixer">Mixer</option>
                        <option value="garnish">Garnish</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
```

Then I'm using another JavaScript function to flip the image based on the ingredient selection from the 2nd drop down menu.

Here is my function:

```
    function changePicture(selectbox,thisImage) {
    var selection = document.getElementById(selectbox).selectedIndex; //grabs what user selected
    var image = document.getElementById(selectbox).options[selection].myImage;  //store image in variable
    document.getElementById(thisImage).src = 'img/' + image; //change the image
}
```

Then below...

```
                      <td>
                    <select id='step1_id' name='step1_id' onChange="changePicture('step1_id','step1_image')">
                        <option value='0'>Choose object</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <select id='step2_id' name='step2_id' onChange="changePicture('step2_id','step2_image')">
                        <option value='0'>Choose object</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <img id='step1_image' name='step1_image' src='img/Willsmallimage.jpg'>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <img id='step2_image' name='step2_image' src='img/Willsmallimage.jpg'>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

The trouble is, it works perfectly for ever category except Bottles. I've tried changing out the images, but it will only work in one of the other tables. Never works in the bottles table.  In FireBug it says that the function is returning 'img/undefined' when I pick an ingredient from that table. any ideas?

Comment: Where does the property `.myImage` come from in the `changePicture()` function?  I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Add a `var i` definition to your `configureDropDownLists()` function so it's not accidentally a global variable.

Comment: forgot to put in createOption(). sry.

Comment: Now, you don't show us the 'actions' 'bottles', `mixers` and 'garnishes` arrays.  I'm just trying to trace back all the way to where the `undefined` value comes from and you aren't showing everything needed for that.

Comment: No prob, I put the code in. I also tried echo and document.write() to test all the arrays & they are all stored properly.

Comment: You put in the PHP. I would need to see the generated javascript for those arrays to see what's actually in the arrays.  You can get it from View/Source in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `configureDropDownLists()`, you have a typo (a misplaced closing paren).  Change this line:

```
createOption(document.getElementById(select2), bottles[i]['name'], bottles[i]['id']), bottles[i]['image'];
```

to this:

```
createOption(document.getElementById(select2), bottles[i]['name'], bottles[i]['id'], bottles[i]['image']);
```

The consequences of this typo where that the image was not being passed to createOption and thus was always undefined.

In the future, putting a breakpoint in `createOption()` and watching how it created the options would have seen that the image was always `undefined` when creating bottle options.  That would have directed you to the faulty line of code - though it's still a subtle error to see.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works great. I'm new to javascript, but I looked up how to put in breakpoints to help debug in the future.